# Java-Streams - filter() + map() - Map objects from one List with the missing property to objects from another List

Tags: java, list, java-stream

Map attribute of one object to another object after filtering list

I have two lists of `Student` objects.

```
public class Student {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String status;

    // the rest code
}
```

I want to get the students from the `list2` with `id` which are not present in `list1`.

```
Student s1 = new Student(1, "A", "active");
Student s2 = new Student(2, "B", "active");
Student s3 = new Student(3, "C", "active");

List<Student> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add(s1);
list1.add(s2);
list1.add(s3);

Student s4 = new Student(null, "A", "inactive");
Student s5 = new Student(null, "B", "inactive");
Student s6 = new Student(null, "E", "inactive");

List<Student> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list2.add(s4);
list2.add(s5);
list2.add(s6);
```

This is my solution:

```
final List<Student> list = list2.stream()
    .filter(p -> list1.stream().anyMatch(p2 -> p.getName() == p2.getName()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Current result:

```
[null - A - inactive, null - B - inactive]
```

I want to map `id` of `A` and `B` in `list1` so that the desired result would be:

```
[1- A - inactive, 2 - B - inactive]
```

So, how can I do these two actions `filter` and `map` in ONE line code (single stream-statemnt)?

Comment: Looking at the condition in filter, isn't using list1 to stream over first would give you the desired result `list1.stream().filter(p -> list2.stream().anyMatch(p2 -> p.getName() == p2.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 0):

> So how can I do both actions `filter` and `map` in ONE line code (single stream-statement)?

That's definitely doable, but it would **not** be as efficient as it could be due to redundant iterations through the `list1`  (just apply `map` and iterate over the `list1` like you've done with the `filter`, which is pretty trivial, so I'm leaving it for OP and reader as an exercise, if they are interested in it).

That the example of how it can be done using Java 16 `mapMulty()` in a single stream-statement:

```
List<Student> result = list2.stream()
    .<Student>mapMulti((student, consumer) -> {
        if (student.getId() == null) {
            list1.stream().filter(s -> s.getName().equals(student.getName()))
                .findFirst()
                .ifPresent(consumer);
        }
    }).toList();
```

The **more performant** approach would be to index all the `id` and `name`s of students in the `list1`

To determine which `id` (the first attribute) are present in the `list1` we can generate a `HashSet` it would be way better than iterate through the `list1` over and over.

And to retrieve a student from the `list1` by `name` (in order to replace the student from the `list2` which has an `id` equal to `null`) we can generate a `Map`.

***Sidenote:** don't use identity comparison `==` to compare the objects if your goal is to compare their properties, and not if the both references point to the same object.*

That's how it can be implemented:

```
Set<Integer> studentIds = list1.stream()
    .map(Student::getId)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        
Map<String, Student> studentById = list1.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Student::getName,       // extracting a key
        Function.identity(),    // extracting a value
        (left, right) -> left   // resolving the students mapped to the same key (i.e. having the same name)
    ));
        
List<Student> result = list2.stream()
    .filter(student -> !studentIds.contains(student.getId()))      // ID doesn't exists in the list1
    .filter(student -> studentById.containsKey(student.getName())) // name is present in the list1
    .map(student -> studentById.get(student.getName()))            // replace student from the list2 with a namesake-student from the list1
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

*Output:*

```
Student{id=1, name='A', status='active'}
Student{id=2, name='B', status='active'}
```